# Is there a way to make the keyboard trigger a button press?

Tags: ios, testing, xcode4, uibutton

I am testing an iOS app in the simulator from the keyboard and would like for the keyboard return key to make a button on the screen be pressed.  Is there a way to do this?  I can move between UITextField's with the Tab key and capture the Return key through the textFieldShouldReturn method, but I have a submit button on the page also and would like to cruise through it without going to the mouse by firing it from the keyboard.  If there is a way to move the focus to the button so that I can use a space-bar as suggested by KevinDTimm that would be great.  Although I can move the focus through the UITextFields with the tab key I am just not sure how to get the focus onto the button - tab is not working at this point.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand you effectively want to do an automated UI test. But in this case "you" are the automation.  Thinking about it that way lead me to [ios-automated-tests-with-uiautomation](http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/04/08/ios-automated-tests-with-uiautomation)  which may not solve your problem directly, but may be the path you should head down.

This blog references Apples [UI Automation Reference Collection](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/UIAutomationRef/_index.html) which states:

> Use the UI Automation feature to write test scripts that exercise your
>   app’s user interface elements as it runs on a connected device. You
>   write the tests in JavaScript, calling the UI Automation API to
>   simulate user interaction. The system returns log information to the
>   host computer.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, the space bar works when you're on a button on the iOS simulator

Comment: This is helpful but I am not sure how to get the focus on the button so that I can hit the space bar.  I will modify my question to include this.  Thanks.

Comment: Can't you tab over to it? (it may be tough to see, but focus should go there)

Comment: No, the focus never gets to the button from the tab key AFAICT.

Answer (score 0):

If focus was on the button, the keyboard would go away.  You captured the Return, why not just call the action associated with the button?

EDIT: Try it on your phone with a Bluetooth connected keyboard.  Do you get the events then?  I think the simulator just uses the keyboard as a way to use the virtual keyboard, not like a bluetooth connected one.

Comment: @Lou_Franco I will amend my post to make my situation clearer.  The keyboard is physical.  I am not having trouble making the virtual keyboard go away.  I am having trouble triggering the method associated with a button from a physical keyboard - without going to the mouse.

Comment: @Lou - he's testing in the emulator

Comment: When you are using a simulator, that doesn't mean your keyboard is always active -- you can use it when the virtual keyboard is showing.  If you want to simulate what it would mean if a blue tooth keyboard was attached to the phone (and therefore could send keys any time) I'm not sure that this will work for you in the simulator.

Comment: @LouFranco I think you are correct about this.  Thanks for taking the time and thinking about my problem.